# fast jump to make javascript object visible on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that scrolls to make an object visible on screen.  However, it is slow.  Is there any way to jump to without scrolling the entire page ?

If there is a reasonably portable method that does not use jquery, I would prefer a native one.  My definition of reasonably portable is that it works on fairly recent chrome and firefox.

```
function scrollToId(id) { //TODO: Fix Jquery madness below
    var element = $('#' + id); //document.getElementById(id);
    var offset = element.offset().top;

    if (offset > window.innerHeight) {
    // Not in view so scroll to it
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: offset
    }, 10);
    return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You could always use the window.scroll(x, y) / window.scrollTo(x, y) methods, which are virtually synonymous. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll

Comment: Jump? If you need jump, maybe good old anchors.... Even IE support it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet for jumping to an area quickly on the page is to use the window.scroll(x, y) method. This does not animate the page, however, it will get your user to that area on the page very quickly.

```
function scrollToId(id) { //TODO: Fix Jquery madness below
    var element = $('#' + id); //document.getElementById(id);
    var yPos = element.offset().top;
    var xPos = 0; //This could be the left position of an element like element.offset().left

    if (offset > window.innerHeight) {
        // Not in view so scroll to it
        window.scroll(xPos, yPos);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_scrollto2

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scroll

Comment: We are still having an odd problem.  This is so fast that it scrolls BEFORE the browser has drawn it, and fails.  With a 1ms delay, it works.  I will post a separate question on how to make this synchronous! (but thanks)

Comment: At what point in the document state are you attempting to scroll? If you are attempting execute this before any images are loaded or before the document is completely loaded, then this behavior may occur. You may want to try to call this in a window.onload handler.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to jump to without scrolling the entire page ?

Try utilizing `<a>` element with `#id` set at `href` attribute , where `#id` is `id` of `DOM` element

```css
#abc {
  position:relative;
  top:350px;
  color:green;
}

#def {
  position:relative;
  top:650px;
  color:orange;
}
```

```html
<a href="#abc">abc</a> <a href="#def">def</a>
<div id="abc">abc</div>
<div id="def">def</div>
```

Comment: How do you jump to the anchor in javascript?

Comment: @Dov _"How do you jump to the anchor in javascript?"_ Not certain interpret Question correctly ? What is "jump" ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much of a difference this would make, but try snippet below. Instead of scrolling it, just go to it.

```
function scrollToId(id)
{
    var element = $('#' + id);
    var curPos = element.offset();
    var curTop = curPos.top;
    var screenHeight = $(window).height();
    return (curTop > screenHeight) ? false : true;
}
```